# "No credentials are available in the security package" when running SP Foundation 2010

Tags: iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am having an same issue when trying to run SharePoint Foundation 2010, and I am using the NTLM Windows Authentication Provider. We are running IIS 7.5, and we have a dev SharePoint site set up on another server, using the exact same authentication, but for some reason, the site on our prod server throws the error "No credentials are available in the security package." This fails using all browsers, and it fails when I run the site from the server directly as well as from any client machine. We have Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard on both machines.

I've checked that all the security settings for the SharePoint app pool as well as the SharePoint Web Services pool matches our dev server's settings, and they all do.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Kerberos is failing on the server. I understand you are using NTLM but the message seems to be Kerberos. Could you please check Authentication provider on on the IIS? If  Negotiate is at the top of the list move down and make ntlm as top provider

IIS - UnderAuthentication - > Providers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Kerberos is not in the list, only NTLM. I've changed this and have done IIS resets since....

Comment: I don not think it SharePoint issue. It's worth checking if server has got permission for delegation from AD.   I have seen people reporting this issue especially if the server is hosted on VM and forgot configuring this on server.

Comment: I agree with @meetkichu you might want to look at the following: [Configuring Kerberos Constrained Delegation for Hyper-V](http://blogs.technet.com/b/matthts/archive/2012/06/10/configuring-kerberos-constrained-delegation-for-hyper-v-management.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When windows Authentication is used , this error can come if Kerberos is not available or failing, upon checking Providers under Windows Authentication setting in IIS, i changed preference of Negotiate and moved it down , NTLM remained up and it fixed my issue